# Java HtmlUnit login with user and password returns to login page

Tags: java, authentication, htmlunit

I am trying to perform a login using HtmlUnit with valid username and password. After a successfull login, I want to perform a few operations on the resulting page. The problem is that I cannot get passed the login stage - I keep getting it the same page. Strangely enough, I recorded a successfull login by HtmlUnit Scripter Firefox plugin and replayed the resulting code afterwards - same problem. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
<pre>
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPasswordInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
<code>
public class LoginSimulation
{
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
          HtmlPage page = null;
          String url = "http://www.ravmilim.co.il/naerr.asp";

          WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
          webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

          try
          {
               page = webClient.getPage( url );

               HtmlTextInput userInput = (HtmlTextInput) page.getElementById("txtUser");
               userInput.setValueAttribute("yacov.schondorf@gmail.com");

               HtmlPasswordInput passwordInput = (HtmlPasswordInput) page.getElementById("txtPass");
               passwordInput.setValueAttribute("5750201");

               HtmlElement theElement2 = (HtmlElement) page.getElementById("submitButton");
               page = theElement2.click();  // the login does not work. Login page is displayed again

              System.out.println(page.asText());
              webClient.closeAllWindows();            
          }
          catch ( FailingHttpStatusCodeException e1 )
          {
               System.out.println( "FailingHttpStatusCodeException thrown:" + e1.getMessage() );
               e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch ( MalformedURLException e1 )
          {
               System.out.println( "MalformedURLException thrown:" + e1.getMessage() );
               e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch ( IOException e1 )
          {
               System.out.println( "IOException thrown:" + e1.getMessage() );
               e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch( Exception e )
          {
               System.out.println( "General exception thrown:" + e.getMessage() );
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is ok. I have tried it manually and sometimes it loggins and sometimes not. The problem is in the pop-up window which appears after login operation.
You can saw it from the javascript on the page:

```
if ($("#ErrorDuplicationLogin").text() != '') 
  {       
   $(".PopUpContent").show();
   $(".pagePopBackground").show();                    

  }

});
```

So try to login and logout manually and after that launch your program. Also do not forget to logout using HtmlUnit. Thank you.

Comment: You were right! I logged out of other clients and waited for a previous htmlunit login to be expired and then I was able to login! My problems are not over though. On the next page, I am trying to set the value of a search box, to click a search button and the parse the results. The problem is that the results are displayed in another frame and I am not able to obtain the other frame. Here is the modified code:

Comment: After the System.out.println(page.asText()) - I added:

Comment: HtmlPage framePage = (HtmlPage) nextPage.getFrames().get(0).getEnclosedPage();
    HtmlTextInput searchBox = (HtmlTextInput) framePage.getForms().get(0).getInputsByName("searchBox").get(0);
    searchBox.setValueAttribute("word");
    HtmlAnchor anchor = framePage.getHtmlElementById("sl");
    HtmlPage page1 = (HtmlPage) anchor.click();
     try {
        HtmlPage resultsPage = (HtmlPage) page1.getFrameByName("resault1").getEnclosedPage();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    framePage.getAnchorByHref("logout.asp").click();

Comment: The first line in the above code should be HtmlPage framePage = (HtmlPage) page.getFrames().get(0).getEnclosedPage();

Comment: I posted this as a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891852/htmlunit-unable-to-get-frame-content